# shopify store collection error when i can add image

Tags: shopify, e-commerce

I'm encountering an error when attempting to add a collection on Shopify. The error message reads: "There is 1 error with this collection: {:src=>"Error updating collection with this image"}". I've reviewed my collection settings multiple times but haven't been able to resolve the issue. Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to fix this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!